# Printing arrays with strings in C

Tags: c

I was just wondering if someone knows why my while statement I have is not printing out the array that the user is filling in. Below I have attached my code. Thanks so much for your help!

```
/* 
 * File:   strings.c

 * 
 * Purpose: To create a small program that should read in 2 strings from the
 * user, “string1” and “string2”, each of which can NOT be longer
 * than 79 characters.

 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    // Prints the length of each string (i.e. how many characters each string contains).

    const int LENGTH_OF_STRING = 79;
    char firstText[LENGTH_OF_STRING + 1 ];
    char secondText[LENGTH_OF_STRING + 1 ];
    int charPosition = 0; 

    // Ask user to type in first string 

    printf("Please enter your first string no longer than %d characters: \n", LENGTH_OF_STRING);
    scanf("%[^\n]s", firstText);
    fgetc(stdin);

   // Ask user to type in second string

    printf("Please enter your first string no longer than %d characters: \n", LENGTH_OF_STRING);
    scanf("%[^\n]s", secondText);
    fgetc(stdin);

   // The computer need to print out the users first string 

    while ((charPosition !=0) && (charPosition < LENGTH_OF_STRING + 1 )){
        printf("%c", firstText[charPosition]);
        charPosition ++; 
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: `(charPosition !=0)` is always false.

Comment: @EugeneSh. write it as an answer - I think you've nailed it :)

Comment: Switch to "do ... while"

Comment: @MortenJensen I have doubts about the value of this question for the future readers..

Comment: Note that `%[^\n]s` is an incorrect hybrid format of `%s` or `%[^\n]`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it is now printing information from my temporary memory. eg.

Comment: @ShopimoOnline edit your question to reflect what has changed. Otherwise, this new information risks getting buried in the comments.

Comment: @ShopimoOnline... add a `charPosition !='\0'` in the while to check if you are in the end of the string. It will prevent you algorithm of continue printing when you reach the ending of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initialize `charPosition` at 0 and then test that `charPosition` does *not* equal zero in your while loop. The loop is never entered.

Your condition should be:

```
while ((firstText[charPosition] != '\0') && (charPosition < LENGTH_OF_STRING + 1)) {
```

If you just had the latter test you would print every character in your buffer, even after the null terminator.